# Failed to open linux dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Every time i start linux in my dual boot i get this message and afterwards windows is started automaticaly.

[image]

I have no idea why this sudenly stopped working because I dont remember changing anything. Does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: You may have accidentally deleted Ubuntu folder from your EFI partition.

Comment: ^^^ or some other situation with the same end result. You may try Boot Repair -  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair - from a live session.